# Gmail Create like this mail+12321@gmail.com

Tags: c#

The end of the username can have a plus (+) appended to it, followed by anything you want - making practically infinite combinations available.
✅ example@gmail.com → example+1234@gmail.com

So i coding

```
Random mail = new Random();
int sayi = mail.Next(1, 50);
string mailadres = ("uyukusb");
string uzanti = ("@gmail.com");
```

and

```
driver.FindElement(By.Name("email")).SendKeys(mailadres ,+, sayi + uzanti);
```

i need to combine like this example+1234@gmail.com.

Can you help me?

Comment: ...do you know about string concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it

```
string arti = ("+"); 
driver.FindElement(By.Name("email")).SendKeys(mailadres + arti + sayi + uzanti);
```